# Postman is not receiving post data on my attributes

Tags: reactjs, postman, mern

I have used Postman before and it usually works when I am testing out routes from my MERN project. However the post request is not displaying my attributes (name and position) on the bottom of the Postman window, it only displays the id, created_at and updated_at attributes.

Here is my code

athlete.model.js

```
const AthleteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    position: { type: String }
}, { timestamps: true });
module.exports.Athlete = mongoose.model('Athlete', AthleteSchema);
```

athlete.controller.js

```
const { Athlete } = require('../models/athlete.model');

module.exports.index = (request, response) => {
    response.json({
        message: "Hello World"
    });
}


module.exports.createAthlete = (request, response) => {
    console.log('create method executed.')
    const { name, position } = request.body;
    Athlete.create({
        name,
        position
    })
        .then(athlete => response.json(athlete))
        .catch(err => response.json(err));
}
```

athlete.routes.js

```
const AthleteController = require('../controllers/athlete.controller');

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/api', AthleteController.index);
    app.post('/api/athletes', AthleteController.createAthlete);
}
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like your server may be missing middleware to parse JSON. The route is being hit, since the database entry is being created. Try logging out request.body in the controller method to confirm that name and position are not getting passed with the request.

Comment: Okay I console logged request.body and it resulted in empty brackets {}. How can I pass name and position in the request?

Comment: I presume that you are sending a JSON object as part of your Postman request that includes the name and position properties? If so, the issue is most likely that you either lack middleware in your server to parse this JSON properly. Provided that you are using Express for your server, the line of code should look something like 

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

This needs to come BEFORE whatever method you are using to pass routes into your server.js file.